# Как правильно реализовать чтоб не появлялась клавиатура

Tags: android, клавиатура

Добрый день.
При загрузки активити, если на ней есть EditText, то автоматически появляется клавиатура.
Как более верно сделать, чтоб клавиатура появлялась, если только пользователь сам нажмет на нужное поле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так **выключить** автоматическое появление:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Так **установить** по нажатию:

```
blabla.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```